# Inserting a Node after a given position in a singly linked list

Tags: java

My code works fine in Eclipse but not in a compiler in a programming site. This code is about adding a node at given position.

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node n = new Node();

    Node last = head;
    int count = 0;

    if (position == 0) {
        n.data = data;
        n.next = head;
        head=n;
        return n;
    }

    while (count < position) {
        count++;
        last = last.next;
    }
    n.data = data;
    n.next = last.next;
    last.next = n;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: In what site does it not work? What error do you get? Is this the complete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go too far with the loop, and also don't check the position is in range:

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node n = new Node();
    n.data = data;

    if (position == 0) {
        n.next = head;
        return n;
    }

    Node last = head;
    for (int count = 0; count < position-1; count++) {
        if (last == null) {
            return null;
        }
        last = last.next;
    }

    n.next = last.next;
    last.next = n;
    return head;
}
```

Also, a for loop is more suitable, and some other things could be rearranged better.

Comment: I guess the if condition in the for loop is not needed as it enters the for loop only when last is not null.

Comment: @Karthik How do you figure? If position would be larger than the size of the list (plus one), then without the condition you will be calling next on null (`NullPointerException`).

Comment: can you give an example of Insertfunction with arguments to what it fails if i don't use the condition

Comment: if the list is `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null`, the data is, let's say `4` and the position is `10`. You will try the get the next node. First 3 attempts will succeed, and the last of them will return null. then you will essentially ask for `"null".last` which is not OK.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice explanation. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Karthik If You feel like this is a satisfying answer, then, please up vote & accept

Comment: I am trying to but I should have 25 points to be eligible to upvote.

Comment: @Karthik you can accept the answer without upvoting. See the check icon below upvoting? That's accepting the answers, once you click that this question will be marked as having accepted answers and future reads can get help from your question this way.